# Trouble importing a CSV from MySQL file to Big Query due to NULL values

Tags: mysql, csv, google-bigquery, null

I found some problems with my CSV file from MySQL due to "Null" values. Since I´m working with MySQL, I have some columns with null values. Now I want to upload those tables (previously exported to CSV file) to Big Query and it shows some problems due to this. (Can´t convert Null to INT values).

Any suggestion of how to fix it? Should I do an extra step of replacing Null values for " " in excel?

Thanks

---